# i am stuck on question 3 and isn't getting desired output. can anyone explain what should i do and provide code for this?

Tags: signal-analysis, autocorrelation

Given the autocorrelation function ACF(n)=cos((2/30)n) for n= -5,-4,…0,1,…, 5 use the simplified Lim & Malik iterative algorithm to extend the ACF to 256 points. Note that the simplified version of the algorithm only indicates that you should correct the ACF and the inverse ACF. When implementing the algorithm use approximately 100 iteration and use progressive correction factor from 0.99 to 0.01 over the iterative process avoiding abrupt discontinuities.

1.Plot the given part of the ACF.
2.Plot the FFT of the given ACF.
3.Plot the Lim & Malik extended ACF and its FFT at iteration points of 1, 10, 20, 50, 100
4.Comment on the characteristics of the plots and speculate on why this algorithm has not resulted in a good estimate and what could be done to improve the situation. Use the paper by Lim & Malik as a resource.

The figures I am getting in question 3 looks similar , there are changes in magnitude only.

Comment: Hi Thouhidul - Please see: https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1777/21048 re homework: "This question appears to be homework. Complete answers to homework are off-topic, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail including your own efforts toward the solution so that it is clear where you are stuck and that you have already done the requisite study required. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand."  You may get more responses if you're able to edit your question to show your work and where you are stuck.